# Write $\log(\cdot) \le -\exp(\cdot)$ in the DCP form

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, cvxpy

I am interested in writing
$$
\log \left(\exp(-\sqrt x)+ \left(1 + \frac{y}{z} \right)^{y} \right) \leq -\exp(-z), \qquad x\geq0,y\geq0,z>0
$$
in the [Disciplined Convex Programming](https://doi.org/10.1007/0-387-30528-9_7) (DCP) form. I don't know how to convert this expression to a DCP form. I am learning Convex Optimization by self-study. I use CVXPY to implement expressions.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

I think I get the solution.

It could be written as

`log_sum_exp(-sqrt(x), kl_div(y + z, z) + kl_div(z, y + z)) <= -exp(-z)`,

where `log_sum_exp(x_1,x_2)` means $\log\left(\exp(x_1)+\exp(x_2)\right)$, which is convex and `kl_div(x,y)` means $x\log(x/y)-x+y$, which is also convex.

By simple calculation, we have `kl_div(y + z, z) + kl_div(z, y + z)`$=y\log(1+\frac{y}{z})$.

Put these back to the original function, we get the answer.